# IDA python Find issues

Tags: python, assembly, ida

my goal here is to search through the entire memory range of a process for the following pattern:

```
pop *
pop *
retn
```

I've tried using FindText but it seems that it only returns results for areas that have already been parsed for their instructions in IDA. so to use FindText id need to figure out how to parse the entire memory range for instructions (which seems like it would be intensive).

So i switched to FindBinary but i ran into an issue there as well. the pattern I'm searching only needs to match the first 5 bits of the byte and the rest is wildcard. so my goal would be to search for:

```
01011***
01011*** 
11000011
```

I've found posts claiming IDA has a ? wildcard for bytes, but i haven't been able to get it to work and even if it did it only seems to work for a full 8 bits. so for this approach i would need to find a way to search for bit patterns then parse the bits around the result. this seems like the most doable route but so far i haven't been able to find anything in the [docs](https://www.hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/) that can search bits like this.

does anyone know a way to accomplish what i want?

Answer (score 1):

in classic stackoverflow style, i spent hours trying to figure it out then 20 minutes after asking for help i found the exact function i needed, `get_byte()`

```
def find_test():
    base = idaapi.get_imagebase()
    while True:
        res = FindBinary(base, SEARCH_NEXT|SEARCH_DOWN, "C3")
        if res==BADADDR: break
        if 0b01011 == get_byte(res-1) >> 3 and 0b01011 == get_byte(res-2) >> 3: 
            print "{0:X}".format(res)
        base=res+1
```

now, if only i could figure out how to do this with a wildcard in every instruction. because for this solution i need to know at least one full byte of the pattern